# slick slider carousel starts before page loads

Tags: slider, slick.js, pause

Modifying my question and sure hope someone can help. I have slick slider set up. Am also using Foundation Zurb "tab" feature so a page opens with tabs across the top for navigation. Since the whole page loads, anything that is triggered by that initial page load (such as the slider) starts running even if people are not looking at that tab - and before the images themselves load completely. What I need is for the slider to begin an autorotation through the slide set and stop on the first slide as it completes one cycle. The slider itself is working - it is this initial start function I don't know how to do. I would expect there is some way to do this in the function call for the actual slider but I just don't know what javascript functions to use.

My function call right now for the slider is as follows. But when people click the tab, it is starting on slide 1 but the slide never shows because it is still trying to load the images after someone moves to that page. It then opens slide 2 and finishes out correctly by going through remaining slides and coming back to one and stopping.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var item_length = $('.slide > div').length - 1;
var slider = $('.slide').slick({
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 5000,
dots: true,
infinite: false,
speed: 2000,
fade: true,
slide: 'div',
onAfterChange: function(){
//check the length of total items in .slide container
//if that number is the same with the number of the last slider
//Then pause the slider
if( item_length == slider.slickCurrentSlide() ){
//this should do the same thing -> slider.slickPause();
slider.slickSetOption("autoplay",false,false)
};
} 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or your code so we can understand better.

Comment: Will the above help? I also edited my question a bit because I don't think I was very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your script inside `load` function of jquery. This callback function gets executed only after the DOM is ready and all resources have been loaded.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    var item_length = $('.slide > div').length - 1;
    var slider = $('.slide').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 2000,
        fade: true,
        slide: 'div',
        onAfterChange: function() {
            //check the length of total items in .slide container
            //if that number is the same with the number of the last slider
            //Then pause the slider
            if (item_length == slider.slickCurrentSlide()) {
                //this should do the same thing -> slider.slickPause();
                slider.slickSetOption("autoplay", false, false)
            };
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No change in behavior. I think, but don't know how to test, that the slider is waiting for the page to load, but something is causing a delay until the second "dot" becomes active. When clicking on the tab on which the slider is going to show, only the dots and not the images are visible. The first dot is "active", then the second dot becomes "active" and it is only at that point that the images become visible. I wish I knew how to figure out what is happening during that delay. Thank you for this function though. This is much better coding structure.

Comment: Is it possible to reinitialize a function? If someone clicks on the tab, could I capture that class id and cause that to restart the slides on #1 and then pause? I just do not know why the images are not loading though. Seems like the load function would resolve that.

Comment: yes you need to first unslick(destroy) plugin - `$('.slide').slick('unslick');` and then initialize slick slider again.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that. Appreciate the feedback and assistance very much!